# Xamarin Community Toolkit StateLayout not showing

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to implement a StateLayout for a Xamarin Forms page as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/statelayout

However, I can't get to show the loading stateview.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Xamarin Forms blank app.
2. Add Xamarin Community Toolkit reference.
3. Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="App4.MainPage">

    <Grid xct:StateLayout.CurrentState="Loading">
        <xct:StateLayout.StateViews>
            <xct:StateView StateKey="Loading">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <ActivityIndicator Color="#1abc9c" />
                        <Label TextColor="Red" FontSize="50" Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </xct:StateView>
        </xct:StateLayout.StateViews>

        <Label Text="Loaded" />

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

And what I get instead of the "Loading" label is this:

[image: Loading text not showing]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your displayed document, you should use Binding on the StateLayout.CurrentState property, then create a variable of type LayoutState on the corresponding cs page, and use `CurrentState = LayoutState.Loading;` to assign a value to display normally.

Comment: You are right. By using binding I can get to show the Loading state. I don't understand why I can't just set xct:StateLayout.CurrentState="Loading" without any binding though. Thanks anyway.